# How to prove that $\left(\log \log n\right) \times \left(\log \log \log n\right) = Ω\left(\log n\right)$

Tags: asymptotics

Is $$\log \log n \times \log \log \log n = \Omega(\log n) $$
How can we prove it.

Actually I'm trying to prove that $f(n) = \lceil(\log \log n)\rceil !$ is polynomially bounded. It means

> $$c_1 n^{k_1} \leq f(n) \leq c_2 n^{k_2} \quad \forall n > n_0$$
>   $$m_1 \log n \leq \log [f(n)] \leq m_2 \log n$$
>   $$\log [f(n)]=\theta(\log n) \text{ i.e. } \log [f(n)]=\Omega(\log n) \text{  and }\log [f(n)]=O(\log n) $$

I've proved that $\log [f(n)] = O(\log n)$, But I'm having trouble proving $\,\log \left[f(n)\right] = \Omega\left(\log n\right)$. Can anybody tell me how can we do it.

Comment: The claim is the title is wrong: $\log\log n \cdot \log\log\log n = o(\log n)$.

Comment: Can you define the symbols you use?

Comment: @ClementC. f(n) = o(g(n)) then f(n)= O(g(n)) also.

Comment: @Atinesh Yes. [But $\omega(f(n))$ does not mean what you seem to think it means.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations)

Comment: (I also suspect you wanted $\Omega(\cdot)$ instead of $\omega(\cdot)$; the claim is still false then, however.)

Comment: I'm really Sorry, there has been a typing mistake I didn't recognize it. Please see the updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to prove this. $f(n)$ grows asymptotically slower than any polynomial, i.e. $f(n) = n^{o(1)}$. Indeed, for any $c > 0$
$$
n^c = 2^{c\log n}
$$
while
$$f(n) = 2^{\Theta(\log\log n\cdot \log\log\log n)}$$
as you showed. But
$$
\frac{\log\log n\cdot \log\log\log n}{\log n} < \frac{(\log \log n)^2}{\log n} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0
$$

**Edit:** this does not contradict the fact that $f(n)$ is polynomially bounded. It is: it is asymptotically  bounded (above) by any polynomial.

Comment: Then How can we prove that ⌈(log logn)⌉! is polynomially bounded.

Comment: You did already: showed a polynomial upper bound upper bound (you wrote you did prove $\log f(n) = O(\log n))$ already). The lower bound, however, does not hold (but you do not need it).

Comment: I'm really Sorry, there has been a typing mistake I didn't recognize it. Please see the updated question.

Comment: The same proof applies -- if $\log f(n) = o(\log n)$ (and it is), then you have $\log f(n) = O(\log n)$ but cannot have $\log f(n) = \Omega(\log n)$.

Comment: I think I'm having a little bit confusion. Does Polynomially Bounded means Upper bounded by polynomial or lower and upper bounded by polynomial.

Comment: I would bet on the former here, since the latter is not true...

Comment: C One more thing. Could you please see the image below and tell whether I'm using the notation properly or not

http://s10.postimg.org/4ccxk8xqh/Screenshot_from_2015_08_15_21_21_41.png

Comment: \theta should be \Theta, you are missing parentheses at the beginning around the (loglog n)! (It's ambiguous), and the square should be inside the o(), not outside (I.e., add parentheses there too). Otherwise, at first glance it looks fine.

Comment: ok Thanks @Clement C